# Minimum steps to one logic fails for some conditions

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The puzzle is to obtain the minimum number of steps it takes to make a number 1. Allowed operations are

```
1. You can subtract 1 from the number
2. You can divide the number by 2 if it is divisible by 2.
3. You can divide the number by 3 if it is divisible by 3.
```

At the end, you need to make the number 1 by performing the above operations. I am trying to obtain a solution that gives me the minimum number of the above operations required to make the number 1.
My code (in Java) is as follows.

```
public int minStepsBottomUp(int n) {
        int[] memoArray = new int[n+1];
        memoArray[0] = 0;
        memoArray[1] = 0;
        for(int i=2;i<=n;++i){
            int r = 1 + memoArray[i-1];
            if(n % 2 == 0) {
                r = Math.min(r, 1+memoArray[n/2]);
            }
            if(n % 3 == 0) {
                r = Math.min(r, 1+memoArray[n/3]);
            }
            memoArray[i] = r;
        }
        return memoArray[n];
    }
```

But I get some ambiguous results.Example - if the number is 5, I get the minimun number of steps required as 4. Actually it should be 3. Can someone please explain where I have gone wrong?

Comment: what happens if it is divisible by both 2 and 3, e.g., 6? Are these operations in order of precedence?

Comment: You should take a pen and paper, do it manually, and compare your manual steps with your algorithm.

Comment: how is 3 the result for 5 ?

Comment: @Bruce Feldman has the right answer -- you have typos in your otherwise excellent program. `n` -> `i` in various places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest *reversing* the problem: *starting* from `1` we should *reach* `n` by using three kinds of operations:

- add 1
- multiply by 2
- multiply by 3

For instance for `5` we'll have 3 operations (multiply by 3, add 1, add 1):

```
1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

So far so good, now we have standard *dynamic programming* problem; C# implementation:

```
private static int Best(int value) {
  if (value <= 0)
    return -1;  // or throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  else if (value == 1)
    return 0;

  Dictionary<int, int> best = new Dictionary<int, int>() { {1, 0} };

  List<int> agenda = new List<int>() { 1 };

  for (int step = 1; ; ++step) 
    for (int i = agenda.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      int item = agenda[i];

      agenda.RemoveAt(i);

      int[] next = new int[] { item + 1, item * 2, item * 3 };

      foreach (int v in next) {
        if (v == value)
          return step;

        if (!best.ContainsKey(v)) {
          best.Add(v, step);
          agenda.Add(v);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
// 3
Console.WriteLine(Best(5));
// 3
Console.WriteLine(Best(10));
// 7
Console.WriteLine(Best(100));
// 19
Console.WriteLine(Best(1000000));
```

Comment: Aside from the typos in the program in the original question, I don't see why this approach is better. It's not faster, and seems more complicated.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: For "...*minimum number* of the above operations" greedy approach (which is in the question) doesn't work; it returns (and, yes, does it fast) a good *(over)estimation*, but not the *exact number*. To get an actual minimum we have to implement either dynamic programming or recoursion with memoization.

Comment: but the original program does use dynamic programming. I mean, except for the typos for replacing `i` with `n` in a few places.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: I have to confess, that you're *quite right*: with `n` changed for `i` within the loop of the original code, both methods return the same outcomes (I've tested `[1..1000]` range). When writing my code, I saw robin's answer (greedy approach) only. I create a counter example for the solution, state the problem and put down my version.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your loop, you are using n instead of i.

For instance, n % 2 == 0 should be i % 2 == 0

Comment: That's quite right, `n -> i` replacement within the loop solves the task (with minimum code changing) +1

Answer (score 0):

If the number is 5 you can get 1 by doing:

```
int x = 5 - 1;
x = x - 1;
x= x / 3;
```